# Weird things with saving entries

Tags: performance

For last couple of weeks I have weird thing going on with CraftCMS when it comes to save the entry. I'm not sure how to describe the issue but sometimes (I cannot find any relation between each of the times) it takes a while to save an entry. During that, I cannot enter the website because it takes a lot longer to load it up.

Does anyone can give me any tips where should I look for the problem? In fact, I have more than 10k entries with a lot of fields. I don't know if it's helpful to mention...

Comment: What plugins is your site running? Do you have any modules / custom code performing any sort of maintenance, long-running API calls or something like that in the background? In particular, any modules/plugins that perform some action in the element save events? Have you checked the `web.log` to see what the site is doing during that time? Does anything show up in the queue list / queue log?

Comment: Are you possibly behind a firewall where Craft can not call home to verify its license? Not that I understand why this could only happen while saving, but at least we had that on certain requests.